# Slider thumb won't display correctly in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm happy an issue with correctly displaying the range sliders thumb in Edge. The slider thumb seems to be inside the track, rather than the outside.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

Here is the code I'm working with

```js
function addListenerMulti(element, eventNames, listener) {
  var events = eventNames.split(' ');
  for (var i=0, iLen=events.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    element.addEventListener(events[i], listener, false);
  }
}

var slider = document.getElementById("myRange1");

addListenerMulti(slider, 'mouseup touchend', function(event){
  var x = event.target.value
  console.log(x)
  if (x <= 5) {
    slider.className = '';
    slider.className = `MyClass-${x}`;
    slider.className = `MyClass-${x}`;
    slider.className = `MyClass-${x}`;
    slider.className = `MyClass-${x}`;
    slider.className = `MyClass-${x}`;
  }
});

var slider2 = document.getElementById("myRange2");
addListenerMulti(slider2, 'mouseup touchend', function(event){
  var x = event.target.value
  console.log(x)
  if (x <= 5) {
    slider2.className = '';
    slider2.className = `MyClass-${x}`;
    slider2.className = `MyClass-${x}`;
    slider2.className = `MyClass-${x}`;
    slider2.className = `MyClass-${x}`;
    slider2.className = `MyClass-${x}`;
  }
});

var slider3 = document.getElementById("myRange3");
addListenerMulti(slider3, 'mouseup touchend', function(event){
  var x = event.target.value
  console.log(x)
  if (x <= 5) {
    slider3.className = '';
    slider3.className = `MyClass-${x}`;
    slider3.className = `MyClass-${x}`;
    slider3.className = `MyClass-${x}`;
    slider3.className = `MyClass-${x}`;
    slider3.className = `MyClass-${x}`;
  }
});
```

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  background: #08121c;
  border: 3px solid #08121c;
  border-radius: 100px;
  display: block;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url(http://d1cxtglzz1rb2m.cloudfront.net/emoji/SVG/02-beaming-face-with-smiling-eyes.svg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

input[type="range"].MyClass-1::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background-image: url(http://d1cxtglzz1rb2m.cloudfront.net/emoji/SVG/10-smiling-face-with-smiling-eyes.svg);
}

input[type="range"].MyClass-2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background-image: url(http://d1cxtglzz1rb2m.cloudfront.net/emoji/SVG/37-relieved-face-2.svg);
}

input[type="range"].MyClass-3::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background-image: url(http://d1cxtglzz1rb2m.cloudfront.net/emoji/SVG/02-beaming-face-with-smiling-eyes.svg);
}

input[type="range"].MyClass-4::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background-image: url(http://d1cxtglzz1rb2m.cloudfront.net/emoji/SVG/19-star-struck-1.svg);
}

input[type="range"].MyClass-5::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background-image: url(http://d1cxtglzz1rb2m.cloudfront.net/emoji/SVG/13-smiling-face-with-heart-eyes.svg);
}
```

```html
<input name="entry.878505724" type="range" id="myRange1" min="1" max="5" value="3" step="1" />
<input name="entry.165236575" type="range" id="myRange2" min="1" max="5" value="3" />
<input name="entry.425406382" type="range" id="myRange3" min="1" max="5" value="3" step="1" />
```

I've check the code seems to be working in Chrome and Firefox. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: My guess is edge puts the slider thumbs behind the track border - nothing can be done about

Comment: @JaromandaX thats a shame

Comment: It's a *guess* - I thought z-index may help, but it doesn't. By the way, this does not work at all in firefox

Comment: @JaromandaX apologies I've not added the updated code to the snippet I've added `::-moz-range-thumb` support to my code to enable this to work in Firefox.

Comment: did you notice that adding `-moz-range-thumb` breaks edge completely :p

Comment: @JaromandaX No I haven't noticed this.

Comment: Perhaps it was just the way I did it then :p

Answer (score 0):

Your `::-webkit-` styles target Webkit browsers, but not Edge. The Edge property for the slider thumb is `-ms-thumb`. You can see the spec at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-thumb and other Edge-related CSS properties are linked at the bottom of that page.

Making a custom slider work across browsers gets tricky. A good writeup is https://css-tricks.com/sliding-nightmare-understanding-range-input/

It may be more reliable to fake it: hide the input, build a custom interface that lets users move a thumb on a track, and use JS to update the input html to match what users are seeing.